# Don't display a sidebar widget when on a specific page

Tags: php, widgets, sidebar

I am trying to stop latest blog items from displaying in the blog section of my site. I have used the following code:

```
    <?php  if ( is_page('blog') ) { ?>
        <h2>Don't display anything</h2>
    <?php } /* for all other pages */ 
    else { ?>
        <h2>Display blog</h2>
    <?php } ?>
```

However, whenever I am on the blog page it displays "Display Blog", completely ignoring the if statement.

Is there something I'm missing from getting this working?

Comment: Did you try `is_page(XX)` with your blog's page ID instead of slug?

Comment: I have tried `is_page('14')`, `is_page(14)`, the title and the slug. Nothing works.

Comment: Where did you put your PHP code? To debug also try: `global $post; var_dump($post);`.

Comment: I put it in the sidebar.php file of the twentyeleven theme that came with it. Trying to debug now.

Comment: Be aware of these notes too: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page#Notes

Comment: WHy Would blog "page" be a page?? isnt a category?

Comment: I created a page called Blog, and I'm trying to call it when that page is loaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the `'blog'` slug is correct, your code would work. I would suggest making a separate template for the page, namely page-blog.php (see http://codex.wordpress.org/images/1/18/Template_Hierarchy.png and http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) where you set up the structure and appearance of the page exactly as you want it to be.

WordPress will automatically look for the file when opening a page with the name of `'blog'` (that is, the slug must be `'blog'`). Also, the code you posted above would normally go in loop.php, granted that you are using the default template-setup.

Answer (score 0):

It's much easier to use a plugin like [WordPress › Widget Logic « WordPress Plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/widget-logic/)